# Crystal Report Error not Responding in Windows Form Visual Studio 2015

Tags: windows, winforms, visual-studio-2015, crystal-reports

Hi EveryOne,
             i am facing a problem in Windows Form Crystal Report . when i Click the Button for Report it Show Not Responding and Browsing. i am using Windows 10 .[image]

Comment: add more details, code example if needed.

Comment: I check Empty Report Just add a title but having same problem.  click button event code  PnlReportViewerTest.Visible = true;
            DarziApp.Reports.AllOrders rpt = new Reports.AllOrders();
            crystalReportViewer1.ReportSource = rpt;